# $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$ a UFD where $\zeta$ a cube root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$ a unique factorization domain? Where $\zeta$ is a cube root of unity $\zeta=(-1+\sqrt {-3})/2$.

Comment: Try to check whether it is a Euclidean ring.

Comment: @DanielFischer Should I consider the lattice generated by zeta and 1? Maybe its voronoi region?

Comment: I guess in the end it's equivalent, but just consider the norm $N(z) = z\cdot\overline{z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ring of Eisenstein integers $Z[\zeta]$ is a UFD. It is a PID, because the Minkowski bound is less than $2$ (see theorem of Minkowski here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_theorem). Hence the class number is $1$, which just means that it is a PID, hence UFD.
Because it is a Dedekind ring, PID is equivalent here to UFD. 
Of course, Daniel is right, and one can also show directly that the Euclidean algorithm with respect to the Norm $N(z)=z\overline{z}$ holds, which again implies that the ring is a PID.

Application: Fermat's last theorem for $n=3$ is true, i.e., $x^3+y^3=z^3$ has no solution in integers with $xyz\neq 0$. The unique factorisation in $Z[\zeta]$ is essential here.